# ld.exe: cannot find -link

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, linker-errors, ld

I am compiling glade-3.20.0 on windows and i am getting this strange linking error which is asking for -link. I couldn't understand what **-link** means, its confusing whether ink is real library name or its something else. I googled it but couldn't find anything meaningful to link

The below is the log am getting.

```
In file included from /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkicontheme.h:27:0,
                 from /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h:123,
                 from ../gladeui/glade-property-class.h:6,
                 from ../gladeui/glade-widget-adaptor.h:5,
                 from glade.h:25,
                 from glade-dnd.c:25:
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkstylecontext.h:1201:6: note: declared here
 void gtk_style_context_get_background_color (GtkStyleContext *context,
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
mv -f .deps/libgladeui_2_la-glade-dnd.Tpo .deps/libgladeui_2_la-glade-dnd.Plo
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g -O2 -version-info 9:0:3  -no-undefined   -o libgladeui-2.la -rpath /usr/local/lib libgladeui_2_la-glade-marshallers.lo libgladeui_2_la-gladeui-resources.lo libgladeui_2_la-gladeui-enum-types.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-accumulators.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-app.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-base-editor.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-adaptor-chooser.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-builtins.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-catalog.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-cell-renderer-icon.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-clipboard.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-command.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-cursor.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-debug.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-design-layout.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-design-view.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-displayable-values.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-editable.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-editor.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-editor-property.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-editor-skeleton.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-editor-table.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-id-allocator.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-object-stub.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-inspector.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-name-context.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-named-icon-chooser-dialog.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-palette.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-placeholder.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-popup.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-preview.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-project.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-project-properties.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-property.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-property-class.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-property-label.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-property-shell.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-signal.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-signal-class.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-signal-editor.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-signal-model.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-tsort.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-utils.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-widget.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-widget-action.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-widget-adaptor.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-xml-utils.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-drag.lo libgladeui_2_la-glade-dnd.lo -L/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lgdi32 -limm32 -lshell32 -lole32 -Wl,-luuid -lwinmm -ldwmapi -lsetupapi -lcfgmgr32 -lz -lpangowin32-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl -lxml2   -L/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lgdi32 -limm32 -lshell32 -lole32 -Wl,-luuid -lwinmm -ldwmapi -lsetupapi -lcfgmgr32 -lz -lpangowin32-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl -lxml2
libtool: link: gcc -o .libs/libgladeui-2.dll.a  .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-marshallers.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-gladeui-resources.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-gladeui-enum-types.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-accumulators.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-app.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-base-editor.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-adaptor-chooser.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-builtins.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-catalog.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-cell-renderer-icon.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-clipboard.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-command.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-cursor.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-debug.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-design-layout.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-design-view.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-displayable-values.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-editable.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-editor.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-editor-property.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-editor-skeleton.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-editor-table.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-id-allocator.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-object-stub.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-inspector.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-name-context.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-named-icon-chooser-dialog.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-palette.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-placeholder.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-popup.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-preview.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-project.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-project-properties.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-property.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-property-class.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-property-label.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-property-shell.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-signal.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-signal-class.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-signal-editor.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-signal-model.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-tsort.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-utils.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-widget.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-widget-action.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-widget-adaptor.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-xml-utils.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-drag.o .libs/libgladeui_2_la-glade-dnd.o   -g -O2 -Wl,-luuid -Wl,-luuid   `func_echo_all " -L/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lgdi32 -limm32 -lshell32 -lole32 -lwinmm -ldwmapi -lsetupapi -lcfgmgr32 -lz -lpangowin32-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl -lxml2" | /usr/bin/sed 's/ -lc$//'` -link -dll
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -link
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [Makefile:790: libgladeui-2.la] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/New folder/glade-3.20.0/gladeui'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:715: all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/New folder/glade-3.20.0/gladeui'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:505: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/New folder/glade-3.20.0'
make: *** [Makefile:435: all] Error 2
```

Could some one tell me what **-link** is?

Comment: Try `make V=1`, it should show you the full command it's trying to execute.

Comment: @ssbssa i tried, this is what it dumped `/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g -O2 -version-info 9:0:3  -no-undefined   -o libgladeui-2.la -rpath /usr/local/lib libgladeui_2_la-glade-marshallers.lo ........`  `libtool: link: gcc -o .libs/libgladeui-2.dll.a ........         libtool: link: gcc -o .libs/libgladeui-2.dll.a`. This is not complete log, its stat and end part. Could you please help?

Comment: Could you put the whole log into the question?

Comment: @ssbssa i added what i could because, stackoverflow has limit on adding content. Here is [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0gPP4q29vqQcXhHN0ZFQUdmamM/view?usp=sharing) for complete log. Please help.

Comment: Can you put your config.log somewhere as well? From libtool.m4 it looks like `-link -dll` is added when `$lt_use_gnu_ld_interface != yes`, so I think your linker wasn't detected correctly in the configure stage.

Comment: @ssbssa [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0gPP4q29vqQVjkyUkVxVFp6UDg/view?usp=sharing) it is.

Comment: Looks like I was right: `configure:4646: checking for ld used by gcc
configure:4713: result: c:/mingw/mingw32/bin/ld.exe
configure:4720: checking if the linker (c:/mingw/mingw32/bin/ld.exe
) is GNU ld
configure:4735: result: no`. Why is gcc found in `C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe`, but ld found in `c:/mingw/mingw32/bin/ld.exe`? Is there an environment variable `LD='c:/mingw/mingw32/bin/ld.exe'`?

Comment: @ssbssa i think i did mess with setup for build tool-chain. i need to resolve it. Well Thank you for the help..